# react autocomplete how to show options

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using autocomplete component from @material-ui/lab/autocomplete and want to get result `title_display` in options field .These results are coming from an api  using axios .

You can see my code here--> https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-dew-zbs8x?file=/src/Search.js

Please see if you can help me.

Comment: show your <AutoComplete component code with the options you tried.

Comment: I am trying to do something like this [https://codesandbox.io/s/dkicr?file=/demo.js] but I instead of assigning variable top100Films .I want to fetch data whenever there is change in input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is `onChange` on the `Autocomplete` component is not triggered and hence the `query` in the state is not updated.

Passing `onInputChange` instead of `onChange` to the `Autocomplete` component and changing `handleInputChange` like below will work.

```
handleInputChange = (event, value) => {
  this.setState({
      // see the change made in below line
      query: value
   }, () => {
      if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
        if (this.state.query.length % 3 === 0) {
            this.getInfo()
          }
        } else if (!this.state.query) {
          console.log("Nothing to see !")
        } 
    })
}
```

Please refer to the library documentation on the more usage.
[Controllable State](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#controllable-states)

Comment: Even with the changes it is not showing options

Comment: Is the api providing you the response? can you log the response and check?

Comment: Well you are right it is not calling for any  response right now

Comment: I am looking into it why this.getInfo() is not  triggering

Comment: Why it was not triggering before is because query in the state was empty. Can I see the changes you have made?

Comment: sorry for the late replies here you can see changes-- [https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-architecture-23957?file=/src/Search.js]

Comment: You need to change `onChange` prop to `onInputChange` in `Autocomplete` component.

Comment: Thank you ...now it's working as expected and thanks for answering my queries patiently.